Dynamic Routing in API Gateway with Tenant-Based Service Resolution Using Spring Cloud and Eureka
I'm developing an application using the microservices architecture with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. In this application, I want to use API Gateway and Eureka to enable dynamic routing. My main requirements are as follows:
Dynamic routing in API Gateway: The API Gateway should route incoming requests to services registered in Eureka dynamically. I do not want to define service names or addresses statically; the routing should be dynamic.
JWT authentication with tenant information: Users will log in using a JWT token, which contains tenant information. I want to update the target service of the request based on this tenant information.
I register my services in Eureka with the format "test-tenantId" and want the routing to align with this format. In the future, there may be multiple services with names like test-tenant1, test-tenant2, ..., test-tenantN. Therefore, I plan to apply the update only to requests that begin with /test, while other requests should be routed as-is based on Eureka's default routing.
I have two specific routing scenarios:
Scenario 1: When a request like /user/{id} is received, it should directly route to the service registered in Eureka with the name user.
Scenario 2: When a request like /test/{page} is received, I want to modify this request to /test-{tenantId}/{page} based on the tenant information provided in the JWT token. For example, if the tenant in the token is tenant1, the request should be routed to /test-tenant1/{page}.
How can I implement this dynamic routing and URL modification with API Gateway and Eureka? Could you provide an example structure or code?

I found it
exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_PREDICATE_MATCHED_PATH_ATTR, newServiceName);
    exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_PREDICATE_PATH_CONTAINER_ATTR, newServicePath);
    exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, newUri);


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
